# Problemas al migrar sqlite a mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, migration

Si pudieras ayudarme con este caso. Quiero migrar de sqlite a mysql y recibo este error en la consola.

Consola:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table blogapp.appointments (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table appointments add constraint appointments_client_id_foreign foreign key (client_id) references clients (id) on delete set null)

It was working fine before.

This would be the table that has the problem:

```
class CreateAppointmentsTable extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('appointments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->dateTime('dated_at');
            $table->dateTime('finish_at');
            $table->double('total', 12, 2);
            $table->integer('duration')->comment('Duración del servicio en minutos');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('client_id');
            $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('service_id');
            $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('stylist_id');
            $table->foreign('stylist_id')->references('id')->on('stylists')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Table Clients

```
    class CreateClientsTable extends Migration
    {
        
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('phone');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('clients');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Friend, your Post has a problem and is written in a different Language than the expected on the Site; I recommend that you translate it into Spanish.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es la columna `id` en la tabla `clients`? ¿La tabla `clients` ya ha sido creada cuando intentas crear la tabla `appointments`? Cuando hay tablas que refieren a otras, esas otras tablas deben ser creadas primero.

Comment: Buenas...Si la tabla cliente ya esta carga y posee datos.